# Custom class with creation constraints

Tags: c#

Imagine I have a class named `MyValue` with a constructor `(int value)`. It is general purpose class, and I can put any `int` value to it's constructor. But sometimes I need to use this class with more constraints. For example I need to force user enter only positive values. I could do a new class that inherits from `MyValue`, but for structs it is impossible.

Maybe it is possible to achieve this behavior with attributes?

```
// pseudo code
[Constraint(Min=0)]
public MyValue MyProperty { get; set; }
```

And MyProperty could somehow read this attribute, and use this constraint in constructor to check
valid values. But i think its not possible.

Can you give me some advices to achieve similar behavior?

EDIT: It looks like PostSharp have this functionality here: http://www.postsharp.net/model/code-contracts
Properties are decorated with attributes like [EmailAddress], and then it injects IL code i think in setter which checks input value. Is it hard to implement from scratch?

Comment: Only check in the constructor?

Comment: Doesn't matter where. I need to build one class, and easily add constraints in my code.

Comment: "doesn't matter" is always the most difficult requirement.

Comment: Unless you tell your class/struct how to behave, I'm not sure what you can do. If you have different code blocks requiring different behaviour then perhaps you need distinct classes/structs or do the validation in that code rather than in your class.

Answer (score 3):

how about,

```
public class MyValue<T>
{
    private T value;
    private readonly Func<T, bool>[] contraints;

    public MyValue(
            T value,
            params Func<T, bool>[] contraints)
    {
        this.value = value;
        this.constraints = constraints;
        this.Validate();
    }

    public T Value
    {
        get
        {
            return this.value;
        }

        set
        {
            this.value = value;
            this.Validate();
        }
    }

    private Validate()
    {
        if (!this.constriants.All(c => c(this.value))
        {
            // throw some exception.
        }
    }
}
```

so you use it like this,

```
var myValue =  new MyValue(1, value => value >= 0);
```

i.e. the initial value is `1` and the value must always be greater or equal to `0`.

---

Alternatively, if you want to, you could read custom attributes in the constructor instead of the second parameter.

Most expeditiously, you might want to use `uint` instead of `int` although this would not be CLSCompliant on a public interface.

Comment: Not bad, but still is better to make new class, and inherit from MyClass and add constraint in construcotr. I need more AOP style.

Comment: @zgnilec this could be an abstract class.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use auto-properties.

```
MyValue _myProperty;
public MyValue MyProperty
{
    get { return _myProperty; }
    set
    {
        // check constraints in setter
        if(value != null && ... )
           ... // do something
        _myProperty = value;
    }
}
```

If you have *many* similar constraints, then it make sense to process them similarly (to example, when constructing `MyValue`, passing constraints as parameters to different constructor overloads) to make code more dry. Overloading comparison and using constants of type `MyValue` is another solution, should be more.